# Adding a value to each element of a matrix diagonal in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
1 2 3
5 6 10
8 3 5
```

I want to add a value (say 2) to each element of the diagonal:

```
3 2 3    
5 8 10
8 3 7
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your sample data

```
m<-matrix(scan(text="1 2 3
5 6 10
8 3 5"), ncol=3)
```

You can use the `diag()` function to both extract and update the diagonal elements of your matrix

```
diag(m) <- diag(m)+2
m
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `diag` function is the best for this purpose, this is just another way around:

```
d <- row(m)-col(m)==0
m[d] <- m[d]+2
```

`d` is a logical matrix in which only diagonal elements are TRUE.